# Pandas: group columns into a time series

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

Consider this set of data:

```
data = [{'Year':'1959:01','0':138.89,'1':139.39,'2':139.74,'3':139.69,'4':140.68,'5':141.17},
        {'Year':'1959:07','0':141.70,'1':141.90,'2':141.01,'3':140.47,'4':140.38,'5':139.95},
        {'Year':'1960:01','0':139.98,'1':139.87,'2':139.75,'3':139.56,'4':139.61,'5':139.58}]
```

How can I convert to Pandas time series, like this:

```
Year    Value
1959-01 138.89  
1959-02 139.39  
1959-03 139.74
...
1959-07 141.70
1959-08 141.90
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Code**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data).set_index('Year').stack().droplevel(1)
df.index=pd.date_range(start=pd.to_datetime(df.index, format='%Y:%m')[0], 
                         periods=len(df.index), freq='M').to_period('M')                   
df = df.to_frame().reset_index().rename(columns={'index': 'Year', (0):'Value'})
```

**Explanation**

Converting the df to `series` using `stack` and dropping the `level` which is not required.
Then `resetting` the `index` for `desired range` and since we need the output in monthly freq, hence doing that using `to_period`.
Last step is to convert series back to frame and rename columns.

**Output as required**

```
    Year    Value
0   1959-01 138.89
1   1959-02 139.39
2   1959-03 139.74
3   1959-04 139.69
4   1959-05 140.68
5   1959-06 141.17
6   1959-07 141.70
7   1959-08 141.90
8   1959-09 141.01
9   1959-10 140.47
10  1959-11 140.38
11  1959-12 139.95
12  1960-01 139.98
13  1960-02 139.87
14  1960-03 139.75
15  1960-04 139.56
16  1960-05 139.61
17  1960-06 139.58
```

Answer (score 1):

here is one way

```
s = pd.DataFrame(data).set_index("Year").stack()
s.index = pd.Index([pd.to_datetime(start, format="%Y:%m") + pd.DateOffset(months=int(off))
                    for start, off in s.index], name="Year")
df = s.to_frame("Value")
```

First we set `Year` as the index and then stack the values next to it. Then prepare an index from the current index via available dates + other values as month offsets. Lastly go to a frame with new column's name being `Value`.

to get

```
>>> df

             Value
Year
1959-01-01  138.89
1959-02-01  139.39
1959-03-01  139.74
1959-04-01  139.69
1959-05-01  140.68
1959-06-01  141.17
1959-07-01  141.70
1959-08-01  141.90
1959-09-01  141.01
1959-10-01  140.47
1959-11-01  140.38
1959-12-01  139.95
1960-01-01  139.98
1960-02-01  139.87
1960-03-01  139.75
1960-04-01  139.56
1960-05-01  139.61
1960-06-01  139.58
```